# Detect image src from html using python and regular expressions?

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

I want to detect the src attribute of a image from the img tag from html code using python. I think regular expressions can do the job. And I created a regular expression

```
\<img .*src="(.*)".*/\>
```

But there are many possible ways to use img tag such as

```
<img src="images/first.png" alt="" />
<img src="images/first.png" alt="">
<img  alt="" src="images/first.png" />
<img  alt="" width="100" src="images/first.png" height="200">
```

So my question is, Is the above regular expression enough for the task ?
Can any one give a better option ?

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/395760).

Comment: `Can any one give a better option` - yes, use `lmxl.html` or `bs4` - but then according to a comment - `I cant use any other libraries in this project` ...

Comment: By option I meant better regular expression.

Comment: @MuhammedKK: Sorry, we don't usually help people to shoot themselves in the foot. Regular expressions are *the wrong tool* for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('img'):
    print elem['src']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a beautiful library BeautifulSoup

Comment: I cant use any other libraries in this project.

Comment: @MuhammedKK Then you cannot solve this problem well. I wonder why though?